# WebRTC and Python Bindings

Tags: python, p2p, webrtc, libjingle

Does anyone have any suggestions/advice on using [libjingle](https://code.google.com/p/libjingle/source/browse/#svn/branches%253Fstate%253Dclosed) with python? Every project offering bindings seems to be dead.